# SAPUI5 MaskInput Format on Setting Value

Tags: input, sapui5, mask

I am using MaskInput to allow a user to enter a phone # in the proper format. However, if I set the raw text from the database value, the phone # is not formatted until focus is set on the input field.

Is there any way for the phone # to be auto formatted based on the set mask?

Here is a sample Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RuFLTx7IlveB1ORVKzK9?p=preview

And the MaskInput config:

```
<MaskInput mask="(000) 000 0000" placeholderSymbol = "_" value="8885551234">
    <rules>
        <MaskInputRule maskFormatSymbol = "0" regex = "[0-9]"/>
    </rules>
</MaskInput>
```

Thank you